# didn't show geofense circle in another device,circle show only in one device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, geofencing

[image: in this device the geofense cricle didn't show][image: in this device the geofense circle is show]In this app i will genrate geofense circle for current user , if one device have at latlong A,B then this will genrate geofense circle at A,B center and other device is at latlong C,D then this will genrate geofense circle at C,D in another device, In this app one device have only one geofense circle which genrate at device current location

But in this app circle show in only one device

Here is my mapactivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity  implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    ResultCallback<Status> {

private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
private Integer j=0;
private Marker mark;
private LatLng location,l1;
private GoogleMap map;
private Toolbar mTopToolbar;
private List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private Double current_lat, current_long, current_geoloc, lat, lon, geoloc;
private String current_name,current_names, name, currentuserid;
private BitmapDescriptor vnrPoint, banPoint;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =  6000;
private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;

private User users,user,n;
private Marker geoFenceMarker;
private Circle circle,circle2;

private List<MarkerOptions> markerList;

private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private CollectionReference myCollection = db.collection("users");
private GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(myCollection);

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private Location lastLocation;

private TextView textLat, textLong;

private MapFragment mapFragment;
private String idd;

private SeekBar volumeControl = null;

private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 100.0f; // in meter
private final int REQ_PERMISSION = 999;
private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT = "GEOFENCE LATITUDE";
private final String KEY_GEOFENCE_LON = "GEOFENCE LONGITUDE";

private static final String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "NOTIFICATION MSG";
// Create a Intent send by the notification
public static Intent makeNotificationIntent(Context context, String msg) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( context, MapsActivity.class );
    intent.putExtra( NOTIFICATION_MSG, msg );
    return intent;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.verticalseekbar);

    volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progressChanged = 0;

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            progressChanged = progress;
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "seek bar progress:" + progressChanged,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    textLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    textLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    getdata();

    mTopToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setActionBar(mTopToolbar);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    createGoogleApi();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Call GoogleApiClient connection when starting the Activity
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // Disconnect GoogleApiClient when stopping Activity
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_logout_option) {
        mAuth.signOut();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        gotologinactivity();
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.clear) {
        clearGeofence();
        return true;
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.geofence) {
        startGeofence();
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Refresh) {
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

private void createGoogleApi()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
    if ( googleApiClient == null ) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
                .addApi( LocationServices.API )
                .build();
    }
}


// Check for permission to access Location
private boolean checkPermission() {
    Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
    // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
}

// Asks for permission
private void askPermission() {
    Log.d(TAG, "askPermission()");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
            REQ_PERMISSION
    );
}

// Verify user's response of the permission requested
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult()");
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch ( requestCode ) {
        case REQ_PERMISSION: {
            if ( grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                // Permission granted
                getLastKnownLocation();

            } else {
                // Permission denied
                permissionsDenied();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

// App cannot work without the permissions
private void permissionsDenied() {
    Log.w(TAG, "permissionsDenied()");
    // TODO close app and warn user
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
}


// Start location Updates
private void startLocationUpdates(){
    Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL)
            .setSmallestDisplacement(30);
    //movement in meter

    if ( checkPermission() )
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged ["+location+"]");
    lastLocation = location;
    clearGeofence();
    startGeofence();
    writeActualLocation(location);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
    getLastKnownLocation();
    recoverGeofenceMarker();
}

// GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks suspended
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
}

// GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener fail
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
}

// Get last known location
private void getLastKnownLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
    if ( checkPermission() ) {
        lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if ( lastLocation != null ) {
            Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                    "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                    " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
            writeLastLocation();
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
    else askPermission();
}

private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {
    textLat.setText( "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() );
    textLong.setText( "Long: " + location.getLongitude() );
    geoloc = (location.getLatitude() + 90) * 180 + location.getLongitude();

    markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    markerForGeofence(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

    HashMap<String, Object> profileMap = new HashMap<>();
    profileMap.put("latitude",location.getLatitude());
    profileMap.put("longtitude", location.getLongitude());
    profileMap.put("geoFireLocation", geoloc);

    idd = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    db.collection("users").document(idd)
            .update(profileMap)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"save");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"not save");
                }
            });

}

private void writeLastLocation() {
    writeActualLocation(lastLocation);
}

private Marker locationMarker;
private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
    Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation("+latLng+")");
    String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title(title);
    if ( map!=null ) {
        if ( locationMarker != null )
            locationMarker.remove();
        locationMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        float zoom = 14f;
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        //map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    }
}



private void markerForGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
    Log.i(TAG, "markerForGeofence("+latLng+")");
    String title = latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude;
    // Define marker options
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
            .title(title);
    Log.e("marker",name+""+latLng.toString());
    if ( map!=null ) {
        // Remove last geoFenceMarker
        if (geoFenceMarker != null)
            geoFenceMarker.remove();
        geoFenceMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        Log.e("geomarker",title+""+geoFenceMarker);

    }
}

// Start Geofence creation process
private void startGeofence() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
    if( geoFenceMarker != null ) {
       a( );
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Geofence marker is null");
    }
}

private void a()
{
    for (int i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS,ids.get(i));
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
        addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
    }
}



private Geofence createGeofence( LatLng latLng, float radius,String id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(id)
            .setCircularRegion( latLng.latitude,latLng.longitude, radius)
            .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
            .build();
}

// Create a Geofence Request
private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT )
            .addGeofence( geofence )
            .build();
}


private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
    if ( geoFencePendingIntent != null )
        return geoFencePendingIntent;

    Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenseTrasitionService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(
            this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
}

// Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
    if (checkPermission())
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                request,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
    if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
        saveGeofence();
        drawGeofence();
    } else {
        // inform about fail
    }
}

private Circle geoFenceLimits;
private void drawGeofence() {
    Log.e("circle", "draw");

    if ( circle2 != null )
        circle2.remove();

   // LatLng last = new LatLng(22.28,73.19);

    circle2 =  map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
                    .radius(GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                    .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
                    .fillColor(Color.argb(100, 150,150,150))
                    .strokeWidth(5.0f));
   // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(geoFenceMarker.getPosition()));
}



// Saving GeoFence marker with prefs mng
private void saveGeofence() {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveGeofence()");
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().latitude ));
    editor.putLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, Double.doubleToRawLongBits( geoFenceMarker.getPosition().longitude ));
    editor.apply();
}

// Recovering last Geofence marker
private void recoverGeofenceMarker() {
    Log.d(TAG, "recoverGeofenceMarker");
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );

    if ( sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT ) && sharedPref.contains( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON )) {
        double lat = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LAT, -1 ));
        double lon = Double.longBitsToDouble( sharedPref.getLong( KEY_GEOFENCE_LON, -1 ));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng( lat, lon );
        markerForGeofence(latLng);
        drawGeofence();
    }
}

// Clear Geofence
private void clearGeofence() {
    Log.d(TAG, "clearGeofence()");
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(
            googleApiClient,
            createGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
                // remove drawing
                removeGeofenceDraw();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void removeGeofenceDraw() {
    Log.d(TAG, "removeGeofenceDraw()");
    if ( geoFenceMarker != null)
        geoFenceMarker.remove();
    if ( circle2 != null )
        circle2.remove();
}


private void getdata() {
    currentuserid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    db.collection("users").document(currentuserid).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if(documentSnapshot.exists())
            {
                current_name = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
                current_lat = documentSnapshot.getDouble("latitude");
                Log.e("lat",current_lat.toString());
                current_long = documentSnapshot.getDouble("longtitude");
                Log.e("lat",current_long.toString());

                location = new LatLng(current_lat, current_long);
                if(circle!=null){
                    circle.remove();
                }
               try {
                   circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                           .center(location)
                           .radius(3000)
                           .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                           .fillColor(0x220000FF)
                           .strokeWidth(5.0f)
                   );
               }
               catch (Exception e1)
               {
                   Log.e("ex",e1.getMessage());
               }

                // map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(current_name));
               // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
                Log.d(TAG,"data"+current_lat+" "+current_long+" "+current_name);
                j=0;
                getalluser();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void getalluser()
{
        QueryLocation queryLocation = QueryLocation.fromDegrees(current_lat, current_long);
        Distance searchDistance = new Distance(3, DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
        geoFire.query()
                .whereNearTo(queryLocation, searchDistance)
                .build()
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if(mark != null)
                        {
                            mark.remove();
                        }
                        for(final QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots)
                        {
                            user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
                            current_names = user.getName();
                            LatLng all = new LatLng(user.getLatitude(),user.getLongtitude());
                            showmark(all,current_names,documentSnapshot.getId());

                        }
                    }
                });

    }


private void showmark(LatLng all, String current_n,String id)
{

    if(!id.equals(currentuserid))
    {
        j++;
        ids.add(id);
        Log.d(TAG, "location"+" "+id+" "+currentuserid+" "+ all + " " + current_n);
        vnrPoint = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_a);
        mark = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(all).icon(vnrPoint).title(current_n));

       // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(all));
        //getnotification();

    }

}


private void gotologinactivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

}
```

I don't have any error but geofense circle is not genrate in another device that is the problem it show circle only in one device

Comment: Where do you call ``getAllUser()`` ?  I was thinking ``onLocationChanged`` could call ``getAllUser()``?

Comment: In oncreate method I call getuser method which give current user data and then I call getalluser method from getuser method to get all user and then call show marker method so. Oncreate-->getuser-->getalluser-->showmarker

Comment: You should try to use getAllUser in onLocationChanged by itself with the others

Comment: i put getalluser method in onlocationchanged but didn't work still show geofense circle in olny one device

Comment: i know the reason why geofense circle didn't show up in other device ,onresult didn't call in other device because locationservice.geofencingapi is deprecated so On result didn't call then drawgeofense don't call, so please let me know how to get rid of this deprecated geofencing and by the way thanks for the reply

Comment: Did you find any clues?  I am curious myself.

Comment: yes, i set high accuracy in location now it show circle in other device and thanks for the reply, if you have time then please check this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252645/some-bug-is-appear-while-check-user-are-enter-or-exit-from-geofense